# Intsalling ruby 1.9.3-p551 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ruby

**I am trying to install a older ruby version using rbenv.**

```
$ rbenv install ruby 1.9.3-p551
```

**I'm getting this error**

```
BUILD FAILED (Ubuntu 18.04 using ruby-build 20191004)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/ruby-build.20191022094814.9394
Results logged to /tmp/ruby-build.20191022094814.9394.log
```

Last 10 log lines:

```
linking shared-object nkf.so
make[2]: Leaving directory '/tmp/ruby-build.20191022094814.9394/ruby-1.9.3-p551/ext/nkf'
compiling callback-6.c
compiling callback-7.c
compiling callback-8.c
linking shared-object dl/callback.so
make[2]: Leaving directory '/tmp/ruby-build.20191022094814.9394/ruby-1.9.3-p551/ext/dl/callback'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/ruby-build.20191022094814.9394/ruby-1.9.3-p551'
uncommon.mk:178: recipe for target 'build-ext' failed
make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

1. sudo apt install libssl1.0-dev
2. curl -fsSL https://gist.github.com/FiveYellowMice/c50490693d47577cfe7e6ac9fc3bf6cf.txt | rbenv install --patch 1.9.3-p551

Found it in the link below.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51986932/debian-9-rbenv-ruby-1-9-3-openssl-not-available